# In bootstrap 3.0 affix how to set active class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I have navigation with bootstrap affix and want to change the active li when scrolling. I have tried what ever given in the documentation but couldn't fix it. Could some one help me for fixing it? You can see my page in the url http://www.thephpcode.com/help/website-generation-using-pcg.html

Comment: I think you need to use scrollspy plugin for that..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The functionality you are asking for is provided by the [Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) plug-in. On the other hand, all that `affix` does is provide you with a fixed `nav` after a certain offset. As affix is often used in combination with Scrollspy, this can be a source of confusion as to the role of each of the plugins.

To use the `scrollspy` plugin in your page, add the following attributes to the `<body>` element of your page.

1. Add an identifier to the `<div>` container of your `nav` list element:

   ```
   <div class="col-md-3" id="sidenav">
       <ul class="nav nav-list pcg-help-affix affix-top" data-toggle="affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200" id="navbar2">
   ```
2. Apply the Scrollspy plug-in to your `<body>` element:

   ```
   <body style="" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sidenav">
   ```

Now the `active` class is toggled when you scroll (see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FhYWh/2/)).

---

**But no different styling is applied to the links.** This is because you need to fix a couple of things with you navbar. `nav-list` is no longer used in Bootstrap 3. Use instead the classes `nav-pills` and `nav-stacked` for a nice effect:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked pcg-help-affix affix-top" data-toggle="affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200" id="navbar2">
```

Also, the initial page should apply the `.active` class to the "Settings" link instead of the "Design" link.

Check this working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FhYWh/4/).

Comment: This worked without adding id="sidenav" and data-target="#sidenav" after adding data-spy="scroll". I already tried this scenario but missing that nav-list is not bootstrap 3. So when I was checking in UI I thought active class is not changing. After you mentioned I have checked in developer tool and found it. Thank you.